# text-center not working in table bootstrap 4

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4 and I want the text to be center in align but so I'm using text-center class  but seems like it is not working in table tags.

anybody can help me?

```
<td class="text-center">text</td>
```

Comment: show more of your code

Comment: It works fine - showing only this and saying it doesn't work is not enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working fine

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
  <td class="text-center">Text- Center</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/674e0yrj/1/

Answer (score 0):

the actual values which you use in the table will make it easier to test if the text-center class is working or not... below code can help.

```css
th,
tr,
td {
  border: 4px double red;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50vw
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class='text-center'> this is column 1 heading </th>
      <th class='text-center'> this is column 2 heading </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class='text-center'> column 1 value </td>
      <td class='text-center'> column 2 value </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> this is also a column 1 value </td>
      <td> this is also a column 2 value </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Typography</h2>
  <p class="text-right">Right-aligned text.</p>
  <p class="text-center">Center-aligned text.</p>
  <p class="text-left">Left-aligned text.</p>
  <p class="text-justify">Justified text. Justified text. Justified text. Justified text. Justified text. Justified text.</p>
  <p class="text-nowrap">No wrap text. No wrap text. No wrap text. No wrap text.</p>
  <p><strong>Tip:</strong> Try to resize the browser window to see the behaviour of justify and nowrap.</p>
</div>
```